# Ajax returned variable issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign the ajax callback function variable value to the existing variable.

I have

```
function test(){

}

test.prototype.click=function(){

  this.count;

  //call ajax codes.....

  //ajax callback function
  ajax.callback=function(var1){
    //I want to assign returned data to this.count property. 
    this.count=var1.length
  }

}

test.prototype.show=function(){
   //wont work, it will show undefined...
   alert(this.count);
}

var t=new test();
    t.click();
    t.show();
```

I think it's the scope issue but I don't know how to solve this. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, using this within another scope causes all kinds of issues, so you need to work around this.  One way is to avoid using this entirely by defining your function differently.  For instance, you can define count like so:

```
function test() {

    function count() {
    }
    ...
```

And just use count() without the this. prefix.

You can also set a variable to this and use that to refer to count within your other scope.  For instance:

```
var self = this;
```

Scoping issues with this can be a pain in the neck and can occur when you do more OO with callbacks.  It's good you got introduced to this early on, so now you know to be on guard.

Comment: thanks for the help. if I use var self=this; How should i call the variable in another scope? For example: test.prototype.show=function(){
    alert(self.count); won't work.
}   +1 though

Comment: You would do the self binding only in cases where this causes issues, which generally involves being in another scope (like in a callback of an outside function).  This isn't a general strategy, just a work-around for the cases when this will get you into trouble.